# Updating asp.net textbox on postback from database displays old value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows

Asp Textbox inside update panel displays value from database in page load.  Button inside update panel triggers postback.  Database procedure changes value to be displayed. Textbox text is updated from database in Page_Load, if (!Page.IsPostBack).  It is confirmed that at the end of Page_Load the textbox has the updated value.  Displayed value on screen does not change to updated value.

Based on other posts, I have tried moving the update of the textbox text to the OnPreRender event with the same result.

My only work-around so far is to re-create the control with a new ID on each postback so it will not be repopulated from posted data (using timestamp appended to ID) and finding the control by the base name using Regex.  This way I can display the right value and read it on next postback, but it seems to be a cumbersome workaround.

What is the proper .NET way to update a textbox during postback and have the value "stick"?

Comment: Query - you trigger the callback, which, I assume calls a button event handler, which updates the DB.  The page load event will run prior to this click event, so it won't have the updated value at that point - is this what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you use your texbox just for displaying purpose you shouldn't use `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`

If you need to use your textbox value. Then

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
    TextBox1.Text = %YOUR_INITIAL_DB_VALUE%;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string userInput = TextBox1.Text;
  TextBox1.Text = %YOUR_NEW_DB_VALUE%;
}
```